# Create folder with parent permissions then add another permission

Tags: c#, .net

In C# I want to add a folder within another folder (or the root of a drive) but I want to copy the permissions of the root folder and then add another user to the new folder ACL as well as the ones from the parent (if that makes sense)

For example... If I have a folder entitled blah and within that folder I want another folder called blah2 I want blah2 to have the ACL permissions of blak plus I want to add authenticated users to that list.

Any ideas?

Comment: Aren't permissions already inherited for new files and folders? It should be just a matter of creating the folder and adding the new permissions.

Comment: I thought that if you changed permissions to folder it would clear the parent permissions first before adding the new ones and so I would need to readd the permissions from the parent?

Comment: You could be right, I don't know for sure if it actually does. I was just asking to see if you've considered this. That's the way I understood the (NTFS) file systems work and the .net operations just exposes some of that.

Comment: Ah okies :) My understand is that when you amend the ACL on a folder it is no longer inherited from the parent and so you lose those permissions when you add another user... I'm thinking I'm right anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main process you'll want to know about is adding/modifying ACLS for a file or directory.

First of all, to get the set of permissions set for a directory, you can use the `DirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl()` method (files will have a similar `FileInfo.GetAccessControl()`) or the static `Directory.GetAccessControl()`.  This will give you an object which contains the ACLs and other security info for the directory.

```
var parentDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\some\directory");
var parentAc = parentDir.GetAccessControl();
```

Once obtained, you can get the access rules for that directory (provided you have the permissions to do so).  You can choose to get the inherited or explicitly defined rules or both.  There is a `targetType` parameter which you can specify how you want to get the identity information back.  You'll probably want to use the `System.Security.Principal.NTAccount` type for a user friendly identifier.  As the names would imply, inherited permissions are the permissions inherited from parent directories while explicit are the permissions added directly.

```
var inheritedRules = parentAc.GetAccessRules(
    includeExplicit: false,
    includeInherited: true,
    targetType: typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)
);
var explicitRules = parentAc.GetAccessRules(
    includeExplicit: true,
    includeInherited: false,
    targetType: typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)
);
```

This will give you collections of `FileSystemAccessRule` objects representing an ACL.  From here, you can take these rules and add it to the directory you'd want to add to.  But in case you wanted to create new rules, you'll have to create the rule by hand.  Take a look at the [`FileSystemAccessRule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to see what options are available to you.  If you wanted to give everyone full control, you would create the rule:

```
var newRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(
    new System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Everyone"),
    FileSystemRights.FullControl,
    AccessControlType.Allow
);
```

To add the new rules, just take the rules and add it to the access control object you want to add to.  You won't have to add inherited rules because... they will be inherited, but you'll probably want to add the explicit rules.  Just be aware that changes made to the access control object will not reflect the actual directory until you set them back.

```
var dir = parentDir.CreateSubdirectory("test");
var ac = dir.GetAccessControl();
ac.AddAccessRule(newRule);
foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in explicitRules)
    ac.AddAccessRule(rule);
dir.SetAccessControl(ac);
```

There is of course much more you can do with this but this should help get the ball rolling on figuring out what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the root folder and make sure the folder is set to push down permissions into any subfolders.  After the folder is created, use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229078%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN article to add whatever ACLs you want to the folder.